# Download drm content via Android Download Manager

Tags: android

I am using Android Download Manager to download drm(.dm) contents. However many times I have observed that file downloading is failing with a message "Download Unsuccessful". But when I try to download the same content again it gets downloaded. I am also setting the MIME type as "application/vnd.oma.drm.message" before download begins.

Comment: I am getting Error_Cannot_Resume error from Download Manager

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?